# Show menu in sidebar if on specific page AND specific user role (is_page, current_user_can)

Tags: user-roles

I tried combining two conditions: is_page and current_user_can but it didn't work.

Found an example at StackExchange where the user role was spelled out. But the Wordpress codex says "Do not pass a role name to current_user_can(), as this is not guaranteed to work correctly."
On the same page, this link is included for reference/further reading:
http://docs.appthemes.com/tutorials/wordpress-check-user-role-function/

I tried adapting that code, and added this to my functions.php

```
function plastics_check_user_role( $role, $user_id = null ) {

if ( is_numeric( $user_id ) )
$user = get_userdata( $user_id );
else
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

if ( empty( $user ) )
return false;

return in_array( $role, (array) $user->roles );
}
```

Then, here's what I put in the sidebar.php file:

```
<?php
    if (is_page(array('page1')) && plastics_check_user_role('Administrator')) :
        echo '<div class="widget-title">Title 1</div>' . wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'menu1' ));
    elseif (is_page(array('page2'))) :
        echo '<div class="widget-title">Page 2</div>' . wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'menu2' ));
    elseif (is_page(array('page 3'))) :
        echo '<div class="widget-title">Page 3</div>' . wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'menu3' ));
    endif;
?>
```

Still not working. What am I missing?
Is it because it's in the sidebar?

---

I prefer to spell out the role - not specify user capabilities - because my 5 custom user roles have exactly the same capabilities, but I restrict pages based on the role.
(Hacky workaround: I could add custom capabilities to each role, but that seems like a strange way of doing it....)

Answer (score 1):

Changed the code in functions.php to this:

```
function get_user_role() {
global $current_user;

$user_roles = $current_user->roles;
$user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

return $user_role;
}
```

And in the sidebar.php:

```
<?php
if (is_page(array('page1')) && get_user_role('Administrator')) :
    echo '<div class="widget-title">Title 1</div>' . wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'menu1' ));
elseif (is_page(array('page2'))) :
    echo '<div class="widget-title">Page 2</div>' . wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'menu2' ));
elseif (is_page(array('page 3'))) :
    echo '<div class="widget-title">Page 3</div>' . wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'menu3' ));
endif;
?>
```

Sources:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458362/how-to-get-the-currently-logged-in-users-role-in-wordpress

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-users-role?replies=10#post-1600295